# Django 1.11.4 Postgresql SELECT ARRAY to django orm

Tags: python, django, postgresql, subquery

I am trying to build a complex(for me) query for one of my projects. Django version is 1.11.4 and PostgreSQL version is 9.6.

Here are the models.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    classification = models.ForeignKey("events.Classification", related_name="events", null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class Classification(models.Model):
    ...
    segment = models.ForeignKey("events.ClassificationSegment", related_name="classifications", blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class ClassificationSegment(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ...
```

I blocked somewhere here and can't go ahead.

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value as V
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
import events.models


event_subquery = events.models.Event.objects.filter(classification__segment=OuterRef('pk')) \
.annotate(event=Concat(V('{id:'), 'id', V(', name:"'), 'name', V('"}'), output_field=CharField()))

final_list = events.models.ClassificationSegment.objects.annotate(
event_list=ArrayAgg(Subquery(event_subquery.values('event')[:6])))
```

I have a raw query. Here it is.

```
final_events = events.models.ClassificationSegment.objects.raw('SELECT "events_classificationsegment"."id", "events_classificationsegment"."name", (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT CONCAT(\'{id:\', CONCAT(U0."id", CONCAT(\',\', \'name:"\', U0."name", \'"}\'))) AS "event" FROM "events_event" U0 INNER JOIN "events_classification" U1 ON (U0."classification_id" = U1."id") WHERE U1."segment_id" = ("events_classificationsegment"."id") LIMIT 6)) AS "event_list" FROM "events_classificationsegment"')
```

You can see the result in the screenshot. I guess I am on the right way. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Postgres has a really nice way of making an array from a subquery:

```
SELECT foo.id, ARRAY(SELECT bar FROM baz WHERE foo_id = foo.id) AS bars
  FROM foo
```

To do this within the ORM, you can define a subclass of `Subquery`:

```
class Array(Subquery):
    template = 'ARRAY(%(subquery)s)'
```

and use this in your queryset:

```
queryset = ClassificationSegment.objects.annotate(
    event_list=Array(event_subquery.values('event')[:6])
)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Subquery' object has no attribute 'query'`

Comment: @AlxVallejo can you elaborate on this? Are you sure you copied everything correctly?

Comment: @AlxVallejo, you possibly tried to pass Subquery object to Array param but you should pass queryset. I've made the same mistake so the reply is just for future readers of the topic.